# Add the java.xml.ws module in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, module

We are about to migrate from java 8 to java 9, and in our code we are using soap, hence I need to tell eclipse to compile with the java.xml.ws module.

In the first step I do NOT want to modularize the project (i.e. adding module-info.java). Instead I want to keep every dependency in the unnamed module so I need another way to add the java.xml.ws module to the eclipse java compiler (hopefully by using --add-modules=java.xml.ws but I don´t know where to put it in eclipse).

I´ve been searching the web for solutions but nothing has helped me so far, the most content I have found assumes that you are convert the jar files to modules (which I don´t want to do in the first step). Has anyone else experienced the same problem in eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to ***Project > Properties: Java Build Path***, tab ***Libraries***
2. Select the ***JRE > Is modular*** node and click ***Edit...***
3. In *Available modules* **select** the **`java.xml.ws`** module and click the **<kbd>→</kbd>** button

[image]

Comment: Many thanks howler! Your solution worked perfectly well for me!

Comment: can not edit in my eclipse `Version: 2019-09 R (4.13.0)
Build id: 20190917-1200`  with the disabled edit button

Comment: @chanjianyi For which Java version? Only Java 9 and higher is modular and can be edited.

Answer (score 1):

For those who want to build **Java API for XML Web Services (JAX-WS)** in a **Java Project** using **Eclipse**, and encounter the following problems:

1. Cannot import **javax.jws.*;** or the "**javax.jws.*;**" cannot be resolved.
2. Cannot import **javax.xml.ws.*;** or the "**javax.xml.ws.*;**" cannot be resolved.

And you are using the **newer version of jdk** than **jdk 1.8** (For me, the jdk version is 15). Your jdk version is the jdk you **dowonloaded and installed on your computer**, **not** the version **showed in Eclipse's Project's properties**. (Don't get confuse).

Here is the cause of the problem: the **newer version of jdk** will **removed some packages**, like jdk 9 removed many packages. (You can see details Here: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/9-removed-features.html)
And the **javax.jws, javax.xml.ws and other JAX-WS packages are removed**, the **jdk 1.8** is the newest version still **including these packages**.

Here is the solution:

1. **Installl the jdk 1.8** on your computer, you can download it in here: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#java8
2. **Doesn't** need to **change anything**, like windows environment variables.
3. Let **Eclipse** **know there is a jdk 1.8 exist**. The **steps on Eclipse** are: Window ==> Preferences ==> Installed JREs ==> Add ==> Standard VM ==> Choose JRE home (The folder you just installed the jdk 1.8, usually it contains these five subfolders: bin, include, jre, legal,lib) ==> Set JRE name (Pick a name whatever you like, you can just call it jdk1.8 like me) ==> Finish.
4. **Change the jdk version** of **Java Project** you want to **use JAX-WS related packages**. Here are steps: Right Click project ==> Build Path ==> Configure Build Path ==> Libraries ==> JRE System Libraries ==> Edit ==> Alternate JRE ==> Choose the jdk 1.8 (or choose the jre just named by you) ==> Apply and Close.

You can start to build or pratice the JAX-WS now!
**Next time** you want to create a Java project **using JAX-WS related packages**, you just need to **apply the forth step**.

After you installed the jdk 1.8, you may encounter the jdk version problem next time you open Eclipse. Here is the solution: [Eclipse - Incompatible JVM. Version 1.8.0_261 of the JVM is not suitable for this product. Version: 11 or greater is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63996047/eclipse-incompatible-jvm-version-1-8-0-261-of-the-jvm-is-not-suitable-for-thi/64049648)

If you still have any problems, please let me know.