# Eclipse - "Incompatible JVM. Version 1.8.0_261 of the JVM is not suitable for this product. Version: 11 or greater is required"

Tags: java, eclipse

I just downloaded Eclipse as an archive and installed newest 64 bit Java and 64 bit Java Development Kit 15. And I get this error. I installed JDK 11 after and got the same error.

How can I make this work?

Comment: See: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM

Comment: @howlger Praise thee. It works. But i'm still waiting for a day when Java and Eclipse works out of the box similar to C# and Visual Studio.

Comment: @CommanderCat That doesn't work "out-of-the-box" either when you have multiple versions of C# like you had with Java. It's an apples-to-oranges comparison anyway.

Comment: Was your Java 11 a non-Oracle build, by chance?

Comment: Both downloaded from official oracle website. Even with one JDK and JRE it also didn't work. Java is just hot mess, you have to do everything manually, which is awful for beginners.

Comment: Oracle provides JDKs, not JREs anymore. Do you get the same issue when downloading Java from [adoptopenjdk.net](https://adoptopenjdk.net/)? 3 of the 13 Eclipse IDE packages are allready shipped with Java: Eclipse for C/C++, for Web/JavaScript and for Rust developers (Oracle has prevented this from happening earlier). In the future, probably also the Java IDE will be shipped with Java. The question is not how long you have to wait for others to make something freely available to you, but how long we have to wait for you to contribute something to the open source tools and frameworks you use.

Comment: Unless told explicitly otherwise Eclipse looks for the default java command on the system (which adds itself to the path).  To my knowledge (which might be quite dated) only the Oracle Java installer does this - you appear to have done this the last for Java 8 - otherwise you need to either add the JVM you installed to your PATH variable, or tell Eclipse in the ini file which one to use.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Downloaded the latest version of Java from the website but it still says jdk-8.0 ...

Answer (score 210):

The **Java to run Eclipse** can be specified in the `eclipse.ini` file (see [Eclipse wiki: eclipse.ini - Specifying the JVM](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM)). Add the following two lines directly before the line `-vmargs` and adapt the path to your Java 11 or higher 64-bit Java VM installation directory:

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-14.0.2.12-openj9\bin\javaw.exe
```

Alternatively, you can put the Java VM into the `jre` subdirectory of the Eclipse installation or, if you do not install Eclipse but upgrade it, install Java 11 or better Java 14 as plugin before the upgrade from [Eclipse JustJ](https://download.eclipse.org/justj/www/?page=download) (use *JustJ OpenJDK Hotspot JRE Complete*, not *Base* or *Minimal*).

Please note, that even if you run Eclipse with Java 11 or higher, **Eclipse 2020-09 (4.17) still supports to code in Java 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8 and even much older versions** (down to Java 1.1). [Java 15 can be installed via Marketplace](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-15-support-eclipse-2020-09-417).

Comment: This solution help me to fix the issue. I removed the -vmargs and replaced with -vm only

Comment: @DipakBari All lines after `-vmargs` are used as arguments for the Java VM. Removing the `-vmargs` line might cause issues.

Comment: Had same issue after changing Java_home, had to run administrator in windows to take effect.

Comment: @hram908 Better edit the `eclipse.ini` file than changing `JAVA_HOME` since `JAVA_HOME` is also used by other applications which might not yet work with Java 11.

Comment: With Eclipse version 12-2020, this did work for me :)

Comment: Make sure to put "-vm" and the path "C:/...." on separate lines (exactly as it is shown above). I thought it wasn't important but it doesn't work when you put it all on one line.

Comment: Echoing @smeier_ec comment about 2 lines required.   Many other places online include this as a single line or omit the .exe file, this is the only one that has worked!

Comment: @DanielWiddis Maybe what you read was referring to the command line. `-vm` can also be used as command line argument. For example, `eclipse -vm ...` will overwrite the `eclipse.ini` settings.

Comment: Your solution has worked for me on Fedora Linux. Of course the path was different ( /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-17.0.4.1.1-1.fc36.x86_64/bin/java ). Thank you!

Comment: I keep getting the error even after updating the INI file with right path. Still somehow its referring to older version.

Comment: @Kaz The INI file is for the Java to run Eclipse. Just use a current Eclipse with integrated Java. The Java JDKs that you want to use in your projects have to be configured in the preferences _Java > Installed JREs_.

Comment: This worked for me. Just gave path of jdk present in C drive in program files.

Comment: I have seen this as item in the list of `-vmargs`: `-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=17`. So I needed to delete this line, but I am no sure, whether this is dangerous. My Ecplipse: `Version: 2023-03 (4.27.0) | Build id: 20230309-1520`

Comment: @BairDev Deleting `-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=17` is dangerous since it hides showing an error at an early stage. Nowadays Eclipse requires Java 17 or higher to run (not all parts, but some parts). So do not delete this line.

Answer (score 102):

I got it resolved by adding the vm parameters in the Eclipse configuration file at the top.

[image]

**In text format**

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.9\bin\javaw.exe
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.800.v20200727-1323.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.1300.v20200819-0940
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
-showsplash
org.eclipse.epp.package.common
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Xms256m
-Xmx2048m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
```

Comment: Can you provide it as text instead of a screenshot, please?

Comment: @PeterMortensen updated the config text

Comment: Sadly did not work for me. :(

Comment: at the top of WHAT?  EDIT: To future people "Get-ChildItem -Path . -Filter "eclipse.ini" -Recurse" if you are on windows.

Comment: Steps to resolve the JVM version not suitable for Eclipse. Do check this: https://paulsofts.com/how-to-resolve-eclipse-version-1-8-0_301-of-jvm-is-not-suitable-for-this-product-version-17-or-greater-version-is-required/

Answer (score 30):

This works for me. Make sure you add `-vm(Path_Of_Jdk)` on top of `-vmargs` of `eclipse.ini`

E.g.,

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.10\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11
```

Comment: this is the correct answer. because the question says it WANTs to use java 11. not to make eclipse work with java 1.8.

Answer (score 26):

I was getting this error on a [Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux) OS, but the following solution should work for all OSes.

**Step 1:** Open a command prompt

Type: `java -version`

You will see something like this -

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_275"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_275-8u275-b01-0ubuntu1~16.04-b01)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.275-b01, mixed mode)
(may vary depending on your computer and OS)
```

**Step 2:** open the `eclipse.ini` file

The file is located at C:\Users\Yourusername\eclipse\java-2019-12\eclipse

Locate the following line -

```
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11
```

Change it to

```
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
```

and restart Eclipse. It is there **twice** so change at both places. You may try to give the Java version specific to your system (from the output of step 1). This has worked for me.

Comment: With Eclipse version 12-2020, this didn't work for me, after showing the launch window I got an error `An error has occurred. See the log file
/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/configuration/1608542182018.log.`

Comment: Hi @KhogaEslam - Did you get a chance to check the log? What was the error? Did you get this error on Windows or Linux?

Comment: I just installed the new version that includes the JRE.

Comment: Yep. This fix worked for me, on Windows 10.

Comment: But the problem is, the original requirement is 1.8. How is it changed to be 11?

Answer (score 16):

To resolve the incompatible JVM Exception, specify the specific JVM for Eclipse.

1. Open the eclipse folder and look for the *eclipse.ini* file.
2. Before the *-vmargs* option, add the *-vm* option.
3. Find and copy the path of the *javaw.exe* file in the JDK folder
4. In the *eclipse.ini* file, add the path of the *javaw.exe* file to the new line following the *-vm* option.
5. Restart Eclipse after saving the *eclipse.ini* file.

As a result, the *eclipse.ini* file looks like this:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.200.v20210416-2027.jar
--launcher.library
C:\Users\Admin\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.2.200.v20210429-1609
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
-showsplash
C:\Users\Admin\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.epp.package.common_4.20.0.20210612-1200
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm                                          //NEW
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16\bin\javaw.exe   //NEW
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-Dsun.java.command=Eclipse
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.graphics.Resource.reportNonDisposed=true
-Xms256m
-Xmx2048m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
```

Comment: how come your eclipse.ini has path to jdk-16 but requiredJavaVersion is set to 11?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue and got it to work by reinstalling using the installer from https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ which includes a JRE.

Comment: All the other answers did not solve this problem for me - this was the only way.

Comment: Please note, if you have got multiple versions of JAVA installed on Windows, and you use the Eclipse installer, the right version might not be preselected. In my case 11.0.9 was preselected in the dropdown, which gives the erroneous message. Just select a higher version.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and I downloaded another version of Java EE Eclipse. I got the Eclipse 2020-06 (4.16):

https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/2020-06/R/eclipse-jee-2020-06-R-win32-x86_64.zip

After downloading it, it worked.

Comment: **Do not use outdated software** for reasons (security, performance, new features and already fixed bugs)! [It is quite easy to run Eclipse 2020-09 (4.17) and only in some cases manual steps are necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64049648/6505250). So don't waste time by using outdated software.

Answer (score 5):

**I had the same issue and the following easy steps fixed the issue**

**Step - 1**

Go to the file location of the eclipse and open `eclipse.ini` in editable format

**Step - 2**

Go to the java folder location where you find javaw.exe
In my case : `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.11\bin\javaw.exe`

**Step - 3**

Then paste the following before tag `-vmargs` inside `eclipse.ini` file

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.11\bin\javaw.exe
```

The below image shows in brief

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. Uninstall Java from the control panel and restart your IDE ([Eclipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) or [IntelliJ IDEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA)).

Comment: It's true. I had two versions of java and after I remove the old one, the problem disappeared.

Comment: There are better solutions than this.

Answer (score 3):

**For MacOS users:**

If you see this error but already have version 11 or greater, you need to specify your jdk bin folder in .ini file.

I observed this error for Eclipse Mat(Memory Analyzer), I guess this procedure is similar for Eclipse IDE.

Follow these steps to find .ini file (You need to find/know your jdk bin folder before these steps!)

- Go to Applications folder
- Right click on application and click on "Show Package Contents"
- Go to Contents/Eclipse
- Open MemoryAnalyzer.ini with a text editor
- Find "-vmargs" in MemoryAnalyzer.ini
- Add this before "-vmargs"

```
-vm
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.12.jdk/Contents/Home/bin
```

- You can start your application after saving changes in .ini file.

Answer (score 2):

I found this topic while having this issue starting **dBeaver** on [Manjaro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manjaro)/[Arch Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux) with the same error. All provided suggestions did not work in my case.

My solution was to set the JVM as per this [post on the Manjaro Forum](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/dbeaver-does-not-start-on-launch-reference-to-arch-linux-issue/51868/2):

1. checked the installed versions

   `ls /usr/lib/jvm`
2. set latest version (16 in my case)

   `sudo archlinux-java set java-16-jdk`

Answer (score 2):

Just add the text above the `-startup` in `C:\Users\username\eclipse\java-2022-09\eclipse\eclipse.ini`

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\bin\javaw.exe
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.400.v20210924-0641.jar
```

This change worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded JDK from https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk15-downloads.html and put the unpacked contents to `jre` subdirectory of Eclipse's installation path - there is a path `eclipse/jre/bin/javaw.exe`. Eclipse picks it up automatically over any other installation.

Comment: I put this right before "-vmargs" section

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue, but I did not resolve it no matter what.

Then it got resolved installing the below link.

https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/oomph/epp/2020-09/R/eclipse-inst-jre-win64.exe

[image]

Comment: It is magic! Perhaps [explain](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64690022/edit) the magic?

Answer (score 1):

> Window => Preferences => Java => Installed JREs => Add
> (browse for AdoptOpenJdk 11) as shown in picture
> Mark as default (Only Select this Version => Apply => Save)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu users, refer to the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64049648/14489697 by howlger. Add the following lines in file `eclipse.ini` before `-vmargs`:

```
-vm
/usr/lib/jvm/adoptopenjdk-14-openj9-amd64/bin/java
```

Above is the Java install location. Change this according to yours.

I'm using,

- Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers (includes Incubating components)
- Version: 2020-12 (4.18.0)
- Build id: 20201210-1552
- OS: Linux, v.5.4.0-42-generic, x86_64 / gtk 3.22.30
- Java version: 14.0.2

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to resolve this **without changing eclipse.ini file**, just reinstall eclipse IDE. It can be the same version or newer one.
I have reinstalled the same version and it's worked without issues, no needing of changing eclipse.ini.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you .
This one worked for me
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16\bin\javaw.exe
added these lines in eclipse.ini file

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31317769)

Answer (score 0):

Adding an additional answer here as I was not able to start my eclipse even after updating the eclipse.ini file with the path of javaw.exe under the JDK. I was running into an exception that started as

```
Java was started but returned exit code=1
```

I had to point to the java.dll file as suggested in https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value:_Windows_Example.
So my latest eclipse.ini looked like

```
-vm 
C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jre-11.0.14.101-hotspot\bin\server\jvm.dll
```

Also, when I installed JDK 11 it did not come with JRE. I had to download the JRE separately from https://adoptium.net/releases.html?variant=openjdk11&jvmVariant=hotspot

Hope someone finds this useful.

Answer (score 0):

Check out your java version and update path and version...
echo %JAVA_HOME%\bin\javaw.exe
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18.0.1.1\bin\javaw.exe

-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18.0.1.1\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=18

Answer (score 0):

I just updated the java 11 path in system environmental variables and able to open my eclipse. My eclipse version is 2021-12 (4.22.0)