# Eclipse is failed to be launched with message "Failed to create java virtual machine" on Mac OS Big Sur

Tags: eclipse

I need to have **Eclipse 2020-06** in order to develop Eclipse Plugin based application with Java 8 on Mac **OS Big Sur**. When I launched Eclipse from /Applications, an alert message displayed *Failed to create the java virtual machine*

Comment: You need Eclipse 2020-12 for macOS Big Sur which also support Java 8 and even older Java version (it just is shipped with an embedded Java 15 that is used to run Eclipse): https://stackoverflow.com/a/64049648/6505250

Comment: Eclipse 2020-12 is the only version of Eclipse that will run properly on macOS 11 (Big Sur). 2020-12 needs Java 11 to run, but it can still be used to develop programs for any version of Java.