# Eclipse not compatible with version 1.8.0_333 of the JVM

Tags: java, eclipse

I downloaded Eclipse IDE to learn how to code, but it only says that it isn't compatible with such version, I tried other methods mentioned in previous questions but nothing worked so far.

Comment: Current versions of Eclipse require at least Java 11, many of the downloads include a suitable Java as part of the download. Go to https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ and try just using the installer. Note that you can still develop code for older versions of Java even though Eclipse itself needs a newer version.

Comment: I believe that you can still *develop for* Java 8 with the newest Eclipse. You don’t need to run the programs you write on the same Java version as the version Eclipse itself runs on.

Comment: Current versions means Eclipse 4.17 (2020-09) and later; see https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Installation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Eclipse - "Incompatible JVM. Version 1.8.0\_261 of the JVM is not suitable for this product. Version: 11 or greater is required"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63996047/eclipse-incompatible-jvm-version-1-8-0-261-of-the-jvm-is-not-suitable-for-th)

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to the directory where the **Eclipse IDE** is installed and open the **eclipse.ini** file.

[image]

2. Go to the directory where **JDK** is installed and copy the path to the **javaw.exe** file in the **..\bin** directory.

[image]

3. Add the `-vm` option above the `-vmargs` option in the **eclipse.ini** file as follows:

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18.0.1.1\bin\javaw.exe
```

> The `-vm` option must occur after the other Eclipse-specific options (such as `-product`, `--launcher.*`, etc), but before the `-vmargs` option, since everything after `-vmargs` is passed directly to the JVM.

4. Save the change in the **eclipse.ini** file and run the **eclipse.exe** file.

---

###### References

- [eclipse.ini](https://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php?title=Eclipse.ini&redirect=no)
- [Eclipse Community Forum](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1105435/)
- [Stack Overflow - Related Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63996047/eclipse-incompatible-jvm-version-1-8-0-261-of-the-jvm-is-not-suitable-for-th)

Comment: The OP is talking about JDK 1.8.0-333.  Java 8 (aka JDK 1.8.0) is not supported since Eclipse 4.17.  That means that following these instructions *may* give you a non-functional Eclipse.

Comment: I downloaded the latest versions of JDK, JRE and Eclipse IDE and encountered the same error: `Eclipse not compatible with version 1.8.0_333 of the JVM`. I researched for the solution to this problem and this method worked.

Comment: That doesn't alter what I said.  Your answer makes no mention of the version of Java or Eclipse.  If you tried these instructions with the versions of Java and Eclipse that the OP is apparently using, **the instructions would fail**.  Your answer should mention this.

Comment: I've added "these" 2 lines between the lines "--launcer..." AND "-vmargs" ... and it works fine! Thank you! ;) _ _ P.S.: I'm using JDK 21